# getting 'expected expression' error for code copied from Stanford iOS 7 tutorial

Tags: ios, objective-c

I copied the code below from the source files for the Stanford iOS 7 course, chapter 13 Core Data and TableView. This line is throwing an error even though it doesn't for the instructor in the screencast

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = self.photoDatabaseContext ?  @{ PhotoDatabaseAvailabilityContext : self.photoDatabaseContext } : nil;
```

The error I'm getting is `expected expression`. I also note that, in the screencast, the `@{ ... }` is appearing in highlighted blue (which is done by XCode) however for me it's just plain black text, which I guess suggests that XCode is understanding it differently for me.

```
#import "PhotoDatabaseAvailability.h"
...
- (void)setPhotoDatabaseContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)photoDatabaseContext
{
    _photoDatabaseContext = photoDatabaseContext;
    NSDictionary *userInfo = self.photoDatabaseContext ?  @{ PhotoDatabaseAvailabilityContext : self.photoDatabaseContext } : nil;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:PhotoDatabaseAvailabilityNotification
                                                        object:self
                                                      userInfo:userInfo];
}
```

Can you explain why I'm getting the `expected expression` error for that line?

Edit

also note that I've imported the file (code below) into the file above that contains PhotoDatabaseAvailabilityContext

PhotoDatabaseAvailability.h

```
#ifndef Photomania_PhotoDatabaseAvailability_h
#define Photomania_PhotoDatabaseAvailability_h

#define PhotoDatabaseAvailabilityNotification @"PhotoDatabaseAvailabilityNotification"
#define PhotoDatabaseAvailabilityContext = @"Context"


#endif
```

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Well then that's not the issue. :(

Comment: If you comment out that whole method, does everything compile okay then?

Comment: @matt yes. Also I included a bit more info in the update above

Comment: Do you really have `#define PhotoDatabaseAvailabilityContext = @"Context"`??? That is wrong (lose the equals sign)

Comment: @matt oops, yes,  that was the issue. Thanks!

Comment: You did very well to include that extra info; that's what clued me in. Upvoted for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
#define PhotoDatabaseAvailabilityContext = @"Context"
```

You should not have an equals sign - just a space between the name and the value.

The way `#define` works is that there is a direct substitution of text. Thus you are literally inserting that `=` into your real code at the point where you use the term `PhotoDatabaseAvailabilityContext`. And so the compiler is choking on the `=`, which has no place in the middle of a dictionary literal.